# SARIMA forecast is just the previous year shifted

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am trying to forecast using the SARIMA model. I have used

```
auto.arima(ts,seasonal=T,trace=T)
```

but the prediction I'm getting is just the previous years values shifted up:
[image]

Clearly the 2020 values are just the 2019 values but raised. I'm not sure why this is happening?

The model it fitted was SARIMA(5,1,4)(0,1,0)365. The data is river flow data recorded daily.

Comment: Based on your model, these are not just the previous year's data, but it may well be that the difference to the previous year is very small, which happens often in ARIMA. The model you give at the end is not seasonal, you seem to be missing a couple of seasonal and nonseasonal differencings. Can we download your data anywhere? Finally, what data is this? The units on the y axis look intriguing, and you seem to have a two-year cycle in there (high in 2016/2018, low in 2017/2019), where does that come from?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/611179/159